# Pause and Resume a Thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have this code to pause and resume a thread:

```
    public partial class frmMain : Form
    {
        (...)        
        ManualResetEvent wait_handle = new ManualResetEvent(true);
        (...)
    }   

private void frmMain_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                       
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(TheLoop));
    }

private void TheLoop(object stateinfo)
        {
            bool hasInfo = true;
            while (doLoop)
            {
                wait_handle.WaitOne();

                bool hasLines = GetInfo();
                if (hasLines)
                {   
                    //Consuming time Operation 1
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(7000);
                    if (CurrentLine < line.Count - 1)
                        CurrentLine++;
                    else
                    {                                                
                        bool hasInfo2 = GetInfo2();
                        if (hasInfo2)
                        {                            
                            //Consuming time Operation 2
                            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(7000);
                        }


                        CurrentLine = 0;
                    }
                }
                else
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(40000);  //Wait to query again
            }
        }

private void btnPauseResume_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (btnPauseResume.Text == "Pause")
            {
                btnPauseResume.Text = "Resume";
                wait_handle.Reset();
            }
            else
            {
                btnPauseResume.Text = "Pause";
                wait_handle.Set();
            }
        }
```

The code above shows a cycle information, it works find to pause and resume the "first consuming time operation" but doesn't work for the second one, if I press the button to pause the thread in the second consuming time operation, this one continues and when the first one appears again, then it pauses there.

What am I missing here?
Thx

Comment: more complete code might help.

Comment: thanks for the edit CrazyDart, I read that more than one wait_handle.WaitOne(); is required every time I need to pause or resume a thread, I tried adding one more before the Operation 2 but didn't work.

Comment: In the Consuming time operations, I read from a DB and use invoke to set values in the GUI. That's all, so I don't think that's gonna be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it guys! the thing is where you put the WaitOne(). For instance, if I have a While Loop (like my example) if I put the wait before it, no matter how many times I hit the pause button, it won't stop the thread, it's logic since the loop already began, but if I put it at the end, then it will work.

Appreciated your help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a [Background Worker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) instead since you are using WinForms?  It would probably be easier than trying to 'Pause' a thread.  You can check the CancellationPending property to see if a user has elected to cancel the operation.  The link has a good sample to look at.

Comment: Thanks for respond ZeroVector, but I didn't consider Background Worker in the begining of the project, and right now the project is so big that I don't want to change the whole thing again. So I have to move forward with try to pause the second operation.

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen someone pausing a thread. Create a delegate and event inside the class or method that you are executing on a separate threat. Execute that event whenever you wish to pause your thred.

Comment: Hello Tono, but you realized that I can pause and resume the thread with the code above right? My only question is be able to pause the thread in my second operation.

Answer (score 0):

There is not any reason that I can see that would prevent a second call to `WaitOne` from working if placed before the 2nd time consuming operation. Since you are using a `ManualResetEvent` the wait handle's state will persist until either `Set` or `Reset` is called. That means if you resume the thread by calling `Set` then both calls to `WaitOne` will pass through. Likewise, if you pause the thread by calling `Reset` then both calls to `WaitOne` will block. Of course, it will not be possible to predict where the worker thread will pause if there is more than one call to `WaitOne`.

Comment: Yeah, so, both of them should pause the two operations when the button is pressed, and continue if resumes, but that didn't work for me when added the second "waitOne" before the second operation, maybe I have to double check. Thanks Brian